# Error 'input data must have the same two levels' in F_meas in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, knn, multi-level

```
set.seed(1)
library(caret)
library(dslabs)
library(dplyr)

data("tissue_gene_expression")
y_<-tissue_gene_expression$y

test_index <- createDataPartition(y_, times = 1, ,p=0.5, list = FALSE)

x_train<-tissue_gene_expression$x[-test_index,]
y_train<-tissue_gene_expression$y[-test_index]

x_test<-tissue_gene_expression$x[test_index,]
y_test<-tissue_gene_expression$y[test_index]

fit<-knn3(x_train,y_train,k=1)
y_test_hat<-predict(fit,x_test,type = 'class')

F_meas(data = y_test_hat,reference = y_test)
```

Above is my code, it always return the error:

```
Error in F_meas.default(data = y_test_hat, reference = y_test, ) :
 input data must have the same two levels
```

although I have check the levels of these two data (`y_test_hat` and `y_test_hat`) and they have the same 7 levels

Comment: Please update your post with the output of the commands `levels(y_test_hat)` and `levels(y_test)`.

Comment: it's re turn 96 values, its levels was [cerebellum, colon, endometrium, hippocampus, kidney, liver, placenta]

Comment: Both? What about the same 7 levels you claim in the question? As said, please update your post with this info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case two means 2, not 7. So it appears, in order to use `F_meas` properly you need to permute your cerebellum, colon, endometrium, hippocampus, kidney, liver, placenta and provide `F_meas` with two levels or it won't work.

```
#' @rdname recall
#' @importFrom stats complete.cases
#' @export
recall.default <- function(data, reference, relevant = levels(reference)[1], 
                       na.rm = TRUE, ...) {
  if (!is.factor(reference) | !is.factor(data)) 
stop("input data must be a factor")
  if (length(unique(c(levels(reference), levels(data)))) != 2) 
stop("input data must have the same two levels") # where we see two means 2
  if (na.rm) {
cc <- complete.cases(data) & complete.cases(reference)
    if (any(!cc)) {
  data <- data[cc]
  reference <- reference[cc]
}
}
  xtab <- table(data, reference)
 recall.table(xtab, relevant = relevant)
}
```

Hope this clarifies.